# Python fastcgi client

Tags: python, client, fastcgi

I'm writing a tool on python for monitoring fastcgi application. The only thing I need from fastcgi is to load ping and status pages (and return some kind of error if it fails).

There are a lot of libraries (from python-fasctgi bindings to twisted) which seems to be capable of this, but most of them are simply overkill for my purpose, and many of them will dive me additional dependencies, causing some packaging problems.

So, are there any simple python fastcgi *client* implementations/libraries which is easy to install/package (to rpm) or small enough to distribute with the project.

**UPDATE**:

Thanks to agf, I've been able to connect to fastcgi app and send some kind of request to it. It's nothing more than standard php-fpm. But I'm not able to get response for any location: I'm trying to from '/ping', which should respond with 200 OK and 'pong' in body. All I'm getting is 200 OK response with empty body for any my request.

I'm doing request in this way:

```
def _load_page(self, url):
    """ load fastcgi page """
    fcgi = fcgi_client.FCGIApp(host = self.fcgi_host, port = self.fcgi_port)
    env = {
           'SCRIPT_FILENAME': url,
           'QUERY_STRING': url,
           'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
           'SCRIPT_NAME': url,
           'REQUEST_URI': url,
           'GATEWAY_INTERFACE': 'CGI/1.1',
           'SERVER_SOFTWARE': 'ztc',
           'REDIRECT_STATUS': '200',
           'CONTENT_TYPE': '',
           'CONTENT_LENGTH': '0',
           'DOCUMENT_URI': url,
           'DOCUMENT_ROOT': '/',
           #'SERVER_PROTOCOL' : ???
           'REMOTE_ADDR': '127.0.0.1',
           'REMOTE_PORT': '123',
           'SERVER_ADDR': self.fcgi_host,
           'SERVER_PORT': str(self.fcgi_port),
           'SERVER_NAME': self.fcgi_host
           }
    ret = fcgi(env)
    print ret
```

I've also had to modify flup client in stdin handling:

```
# Transfer wsgi.input to FCGI_STDIN
content_length = int(environ.get('CONTENT_LENGTH') or 0)
s = ''
while True:
    chunk_size = min(content_length, 4096)
    #s = environ['wsgi.input'].read(chunk_size)
    content_length -= len(s)
    rec = Record(FCGI_STDIN, requestId)
    rec.contentData = s
    rec.contentLength = len(s)
    rec.write(sock)

    if not s: break
```

Note added `s=''` instead of `s = environ['wsgi.input'].read(chunk_size)`, which is part of some wsgi-related stuff from flup. So it should send empty stdin.

Also, I've modified flup to `return status, headers, result`.

I've checked response reading code and it seems to be fine: there's really empty body from fpm. I've checked network communications with wireshard, and it seems fine for me - all params are being transferred.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**:

The problem was with fastcgi param filtering function: it was filtering out a lot of usefull params like DOCUMENT_ROOT, SCRIPT_FILENAME and so on. After disabling this, everything is working well.

For anyone interested, here is the modified client: https://bitbucket.org/rvs/ztc/src/6ec59525156d/src/ztc/lib/flup_fcgi_client.py, and here is usage example: https://bitbucket.org/rvs/ztc/src/6ec59525156d/src/ztc/php/fpm.py

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although `flup` is primarily used as a fastcgi *server*, it also includes a fastcgi client.

http://hg.saddi.com/flup-server/file/tip/flup/client/fcgi_app.py

It appears to be a single file standalone implementation with no dependencies. It has a permissive license.

Comment: Hmm, after changing some code (commented stdin handling) I'm able to connect to fastcgi server, but can't get answer - it always returns 200 with empty body for some reason. Any ideas why?

Comment: It looks to me like the stdin handling is what passed the input to the FCGI server, so you're probably sending an empty request if you've commented that out.

Comment: I've actually not commented, but just sending empty stdin. If I understood correct (from fascgi protocol docs and php-fpm source code), stdin is only being used to pass post data, all other information are being passed via params. Please, question edit with more details.

Comment: Oh, nevermind - problem was not with stdin, but with some FASTCGI_PARAMS filtered by flup for some reason.

Comment: fcgi_app.py has a dependency on WSGIServer, JFYI.