# Python: emulate the functionality of "cgi-fcgi" program

Tags: python, cgi, fastcgi

I need to periodically pull status information from PHP-FPM. Currently I just parse the output of the following script:

```sh
export SCRIPT_NAME=/status
export SCRIPT_FILENAME=/status
export REQUEST_METHOD=GET
/usr/bin/cgi-fcgi -bind -connect /tmp/php5-fpm.sock
```

However, if possible, I'd like my Python program to actually do the `cgi-fcgi` stuff on its own.

I've tried searching for how Python can invoke CGI/FastCGI; unfortunately, all docs I found always talk about how to invoke a Python program via CGI/FastCGI. That is, Python on the 'server' side.

So, how do I implement a CGI/FastCGI 'client' on Python?

(Note that the cgi-fcgi allows direct access to the CGI/FastCGI listener; that's what I'm looking for)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python fastcgi client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801673/python-fastcgi-client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've voted as duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6801673/python-fastcgi-client).

Still, I want to document my solution:

1. I use a modified `fcgi_app` module from `flup` (namely, *flup.client.fcgi_app*)
2. Modification done like in the linked question, but I used a 'pre-made' solution from [this Gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/wofeiwo/3720207#file-flup_fcgi_client-py). It's simple, and it doesn't seem to have any dependencies outside of standard modules.
3. Invocation as simple as the following:

   ```
   # "flup_fcgi_client.py" is the modified flup.client.fcgi_app module
   # located in the same directory
   import flup_fcgi_client as fcgi_client
   fcgi = fcgi_client.FCGIApp(connect='/path/to/socket')
   script = '/status'
   query = 'json'
   env = {
       'SCRIPT_NAME': script,
       'SCRIPT_FILENAME': script,
       'QUERY_STRING': query,
       'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET'}

   code, headers, out, err = fcgi(env)

   # Handle return values here...
   ```